# Exploding a string

Tags: php

What I am trying to achieve is to explode a string into an array as follows:

```
$arr = explode('<some_tag></some_tag>', $str);
```

But I want to explode it even if there might be something between the tags:

```
$str = '<some_tag>text<some_tag>');
```

Could you please suggest how to settle down the problem?

Comment: You're going to have to give some more details.  Explode?

Comment: Will `<some_tag>` always have no attributes?

Answer (score 3):

Given the information you've provided, I can only guess at what you want, but it looks like you're trying to parse XML.  If that's the case, I would suggest giving SimpleXML a try.

http://php.net/manual/en/book.simplexml.php

It comes standard with PHP, but there are some minor bugs in early versions of PHP 5.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `preg_split()` to split a string by a pattern:

```
$arr = preg_split('!<some_tag>(.*?)</some_tag>!', $str);
```